# How to map the matched recordings and transcripts from onlineMeeting APIs?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

#### Must Need Feature in onlineMeeting Graph API

I am trying to get recordings and transcripts on an onlineMeeting, I am getting responses but two major issue I found using the APIs are:

1. There is no way to map each recordings with its respective transcripts when there are multiple recordings and transcripts associated to same meetingid.
2. There is no option to sort the response by createdtime

- `transcripts` returns createdTime in descending order
- `recordings` returns createdTime in ascending order
- When I use `$orderby`, I get this error `The query specified in the URI is not valid. Query option 'OrderBy' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings`

**Has anybody found a way to map these two or any identifier to map this, depending on createdTime is tricky**

[image: Ref Image]

Need a option to map recordings and its transcripts linked

Comment: Hi Harry,
As of now there is no such way to map both transcription and recording. So, I suggest you to raise a feature request for this issue at https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472